# JAXB marshalling one POJO property into another

Tags: java, jaxb

I get POJO that I get from database:

```
@Entity
public class Application implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "XMLOTHERINFORMATION", columnDefinition="XMLType")
private String xmlOtherInformation;

...
```

I want somehow create a getter for transient property for retrive unmarshalled class. I think that marshall/unmarshall in getter each time it has called is bad idea because xmlOtherInformation may be large and I am afraid it makes performance worse. Also there is another issue I String property and XMLClass should be synchronized before persistance. Any ideas how to deal with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reach synchronization between two data structures I can recommend two options :

1) Use one data type (POJO preferable) in all your application and transform it to XML when needed. At this point you know that you transforming latest state of object.

2) Create a wrapper class that will contain both version of data and manage them separately. This will avoid transformation each time when you need some data type but also will decrease your performance and will allocate more memory.

Any way you have to decide what to do depending on your task. If you know that data going to be changed very frequently but not read then you may operate with single object and transform it in into another state when needed. In other case, if you have very frequently read operation then would be better to contain both data types in memory but then update will took more time.